# React Routing with Express, Webpack dev middleware, React router dom

Tags: reactjs, express, webpack, react-router-dom

I have trouble in routing using react-router-dom and custom dev server using express, webpack-dev-middleware, webpack-hot-middleware.

This is my webpack config.

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        // 'react-hot-loader/patch',
        'webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true',
        './index.js'
    ],
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: path.join(__dirname, './dist'),
        publicPath: '/',
        clean: true,
        chunkFilename: '[name].chunk.js',
    },
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ['babel-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.s[ac]ss$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/,
                type: 'asset/resource'
            },
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.join(__dirname, "public", "index.html"),
            title: 'Title'
        }),
    ],
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            chunks: 'all',
        },
    },
}
```

This is my custom dev express server.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const webpackDevMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware');
const webpackHotMiddleware = require('webpack-hot-middleware');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const app = express();
const config = require("./webpack.dev.config");

const compiler = webpack(config);

//Enable "webpack-dev-middleware"
app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {
    publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
    stats: {
        chunks: false,
        hash: false,
        modules: false,
        version: false,
        assets: false,
        entrypoints: false,
        builtAt: false,
    }
}));

//Enable "webpack-hot-middleware"
app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler));

app.use(express.static('./public'));


// serve the routes
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
     fs.readFile(path.join(compiler.outputPath, 'index.html'), (err, file) => {
        if (err) {
            res.sendStatus(404);
        } else {
            res.send(file.toString());
        }
    });
});

app.listen(8000, () => console.log('server listening on port 8000\n'))
```

When I open the application and all the routes are giving 404 not found. But when I add an option of writeToDisk to compiler options then everything is normal. I want the routes to work without writing to the disk. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance !!

This is my folder Structure

[image: Folder Structure]

Comment: Where is your `index.html` coming from? It looks like you rely on Webpack to produce or copy it to the `public` folder? If so, then you definitely need `writeToDisk`. Make sure it exists, if you try to read it from disk (which is what you are doing in `fs.readFile(path.join(compiler.outputPath, 'index.html')`)

Comment: Yes, I'm have index.html file in public folder and I'm using it as a template to Htmlwebapckplugin. But the plugin creates a new index.html file right ? That's what is there in documentation. Is there any way to place it somewhere or what config should I use so that I don't need to write it to disk.

Comment: The solution seems to be here: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware/issues/88#issuecomment-252048006

Comment: Alternatively, the official documentation suggests using `outputFileSystem.readFile*`: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware#server-side-rendering

Comment: @Domi Thanks a lot the app.use(instance) twice worked for me and can you tell me is my config work well with redux as well for development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution to this problem was posted on the Github issue page [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware/issues/88#issuecomment-252048006).

In order to use `webpack-middleware` to serve files from memory, without writing them to disk, while also being able to refer to the files explicitely (e.g. in `res.render`), the proposed solution is to add `webpackMiddleware` twice, before and after `historyApiFallback`, like so:

```js
var webpackMiddleware = require("webpack-dev-middleware");
var historyApiFallback = require("connect-history-api-fallback");
var instance = webpackMiddleware(...);
app.use(instance);
app.use(historyApiFallback());
app.use(instance);
```